# Can I deploy MongoDB community edition without atlas on Heroku

Tags: mongodb, heroku

I want to deploy a react app I have been making that uses Mongo DB but I have heard that I can use Mongo DB Community edition for production on Stack Overflow.

Now I have been trying to understand what they mean exactly by production.

Does that mean I can use that in production completely for free on Heroku or does that mean I can develop the app using the community edition then use Mongo Atlas when deploying?

Finally, if I can not use the community edition on Heroku, what would be the cheapest way to use Mongo DB because it's very likely I am going to go over the 500mb limit that atlas provides for free.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with AWS, then you can create an EC2 instance with 20GB space and install MongoDB community edition there, AWS offer 1-year Free tier
You can check out there [this Link](https://aws.amazon.com/free/?all-free-tier.sort-by=item.additionalFields.SortRank&all-free-tier.sort-order=asc&awsf.Free%20Tier%20Types=*all&awsf.Free%20Tier%20Categories=*all), For instance type you can select t2.micro which provides you 1GB ram and 1vCPU

So this is one approach you can try. Thought it requires efforts in sense of installing MongoDB, securing it, and having a backup of the database. So it depends on which direction you prefer, using self-managed server or using managed service like MongoDB Atlas.